# arcpy Tool works in debug mode but not in normal model

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, tools

When I try to run the following simple script from arcmap it fails but when run using right--click debug and then F9 (debug) in python scripter it works fine. I don't understand why???

[image]

```
# Modified by: Georgec Corea (ATGIS) coreagc@gmail.com

# Author:  ESRI
# Date:    July 5, 2010
# Version: ArcGIS 10.0
# Purpose: This script will print one or more map documents to a local printer.
#          The script is intended to run within a script tool.  There are two
#          parameters:
#               1) Select Map Documents to Print,
#               2) Select Output Printer (auto populated using a validation script)
#
#Notes: The print order of the MXDs is based on how they are entered.  The MXD
#       at the top of the list is first followed by those below it.

import arcpy, string, datetime, shutil, os
import arcpy.mapping as MAP

#Read input parameters from script tool
MXDList = string.split(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), ";")
#printer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

count=0
#Loop through each MXD and print
for MXDPath in MXDList:
    count=count+1
    arcpy.AddMessage(str(count)+'. Working on '+str(MXDPath)+' @ '+str(datetime.datetime.now())+"\n")
##    try:
    mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MXDPath)
    outPDFpath = mxd.filePath[:mxd.filePath.rfind('.')]+'.pdf'
    ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages
    #MXD = MAP.MapDocument(mxd)
        #arcpy.AddMessage(ddp, MXD)
    if str(os.path.isfile(outPDFpath))=='False':
            outputPDF = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(outPDFpath)
            mxd.dataDrivenPages.exportToPDF(outPDFpath)
        #arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, outPDFpath)
            name='c:\\temp\\'+outPDFpath[outPDFpath.rfind('\\'):]
            shutil.copy2(outPDFpath,name)
            arcpy.AddMessage('Printed '+str(outPDFpath)+' @ '+str(datetime.datetime.now())+"\n")
    else:
            arcpy.AddMessage('File Exists '+str(outPDFpath)+' skipped pdf creation @ '+str(datetime.datetime.now())+"\n")
##    except:
##        errorm=arcpy.GetMessages()
##        arcpy.AddMessage(' Error creating file...' +str(outPDFpath)+'\n'+str(errorm)+'\n'+' continuing...')

    #MAP.PrintMap(MXD, printer)
    #Remove variable reference to file
del mxd
```

**When run in debug**

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to include the error that it fails with when run in ArcMap.

Comment: no error message. It's just the output that I included in the screen grab.

Comment: Looking at the graphic you included, it is unclear where you are originally trying to run this script.  You have ArcCatalog open.  Is this where the script fails when run initially?  Have you tried to run it in ArcMap?  There may be a difference there.  In your comment you say no error message.  Does it just get caught in a loop and hang, or end with no visible result?  Please give some context to the screen grab.  In general, more written detail to clarify what we are seeing in the screen grab would help greatly at this point.

Comment: Sorry...I have tried in arcmap and arcatalog. It just ends (saying tool failed) but no visible result.

Comment: A trick I use in this case is to either 1) import traceback at the top and wrap the whole script in a try block and them manually use arcpy.AddError(traceback.format_exc()) to get a better stacktrace, or 2) Run it from the command line and get the traceback. You'll have a much better idea of what's going on and we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the tool to run only in the foreground and after that it works fine. It would be nice to understand what part of the script can not be run in background mode in a tool.

Thanks Get Spatial and Nicksan for your input.